# Limiting font colors while creating a post?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, web-part, modern-experience, sitepages

Is there a way to limit a font color while creating a post to black only?

I'm also interested with other limitations like Normal font is 18px only and Headline is 28 etc.

Is there way to do it for example using PowerShell or am I asking too much?

Comment: Are you using "Text" web part in modern experience?

Comment: Yes. I have made a costum theme some time ago. So when I open FOnt color settins in "Text" web part there are two types of color options. Theme colors and Default colors. I'm fine with theme colors showing but I want to hide the default colors-option.

Answer (score 0):

**No**.

Unfortunately, there is no way to limit the font color & size in SharePoint Online.

**Documentation**: [Add text, tables, and images to your page with the Text web part](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-text-tables-and-images-to-your-page-with-the-text-web-part-729c0aa1-bc0d-41e3-9cde-c60533f2c801)